# Open SSL generate x509 self signed certificate with Friendly Name

Tags: openssl, x509certificate

I am creating self signed certificate using following command.

```
req -x509 -sha256 -nodes -days 1825 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout my_key.key -out my_cert.crt -addext "subjectAltName = DNS: FQDN of Machine"
```

The certificate is created successfully. I want to add the *Friendly Name* for the certificate as well how can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

`Friendly Name` is not part of certificate. You need to export your certificate to PFX:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in my_cert.crt -inkey my_key.key -name "My Friendly Name" -out my_cert.pfx
```

You can't have friendly name outside of PKCS#12 container or Microsoft X.509 store.

Comment: It doesn't matter what environment you use. PKCS#9 attributes are not part of X.509 certificate. And if you are on Windows, is there a reason to use OpenSSL to generate certificates? I would recommend to use `New-SelfSignedCertificate` PowerShell cmdlet which better integrates with Windows.

Comment: I can install .pfx file in windows trusted store.?

Comment: Why not? It would be better if you provide more details on your intention. Currently, I'm not sure what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Actually I need certificate and Key in PEM format that is required by the load balancer. After using New-SelfSignedCertificate can I convert the certificate and key to PEM format using power shell script?

Comment: Does your load balancer support PFX? Or it requires separate cert and key files?

Comment: It requires separate key and cert file in PEM format.

Comment: Ok, then your OpenSSL use is legit. But you don't need PFX and you cannot attach friendly name to certificate/key pair.

Comment: The .crt file will be installed on client machine that will send request to load balancer. If client want to remove the certificate we can give them instruction to remove it by finding the certificate in mmc using combination of Issued To and friendly name of certificate the Issuer to will have FQDN of load balancer machine and Friendly Name will have name relevant to the company etc.

Comment: Please, start a new thread where you provide all information you posted here in comments, because your problem is slightly different than you originally asked. And provide information what is the purpose of certificate installed on client machine. It is unclear. Anyway, the discussion went beyond the scope of your original question

Comment: If you want to add a friendly name to certificate you added to your Windows trust store, open the certmgr,  navigated to the certificate that you want to add or change the friendly name, right click, select properties.  In Properties dialog that appears, add or change the Friendly name field (it's edittable), click OK.